# HTML5 aside correct use

Tags: html

In the following HTML syntax, should the `meta` div be inside the `header`? It just contain date and author name and should appear under heading. Also is the `aside` being used correctly or should the `figure` be used instead of `aside`?

```
<article class="article">
    <header>Heading</header>
    <div class="meta"> date and author info. </div> 
    <div class="wrap">
        <aside class="thumbnail"> <!-- left -->
            <img src="abc.jpg" />
        </aside>        
        <div class="content"> <!-- right -->
            ...
        </div>  
    </div>
</article>
```

Comment: I've multiple articles wrapped in the section tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
<div class="meta"> date and author info. </div>
```

the following would be better

```
<footer> date and author info. </footer>
```

The [HTML5 spec for `<footer>`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-footer-element.html#the-footer-element) says:

> The footer element represents a footer for its nearest ancestor
>   sectioning content or sectioning root element. A footer typically
>   contains information about its section such as who wrote it, links to
>   related documents, copyright data, and the like.

and also

> Footers don't necessarily have to appear at the end of a section...

For `<aside>`, the [HTML5 spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-aside-element.html#the-aside-element) says:

> The aside element represents a section of a page that consists of
>   content that is tangentially related to the content around the aside
>   element, and which could be considered separate from that content.

This is somewhat trickier to interpret, but I would say the the thumbnail forms an integral part of the content of the article rather than being tangentially related to it.

In fact, in the absence of data to the contrary, I don't see the need for a wrapper around the `<img>` element at all. Just use:

```
<img src="abc.jpg" class="thumbnail" alt="A B C" />
```

If you need a wrapper for styling purposes, use a `<div>`

Comment: I believe you mean "HTML5 spec" and not "HTML6 spec" ;)

Answer (score 0):

The meta tag in mentioned in between the `<head></head>` code...

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

The right procedure in right html5 code is...

```
<body><div class="container">
  <header>Header</header>
  <div class="sidebar1">
    <aside>
      <p>Paragraph</p>
      <p>Paragraph</p>
    </aside>
  <!-- end .sidebar1 --></div>
  <article class="content">
    <h1>Instructions</h1>
    <section>
     <p>Paragraph</p>
      <p>Paragraph</p>
      <p>Paragraph</p>
    </section>
  <!-- end .content --></article>

  <footer>Footer</footer>
  <!-- end .container --></div></body>
```

Take a help from this...

whereas aside is a new html5 tag which is for left or right column side of the page...

Css for aside:

```
aside {
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you read the question properly? The OP is talking about the `div` element with a class name of `meta`.

Answer (score 0):

had I been at your place, I would have written the above code as below:

```
<header>Heading</header>
<section class="article">

    <div class="meta"> date and author info. </div> 
    <article class="wrap">
        <div class="thumbnail"> <!-- left -->
            <img src="abc.jpg" />
        </div>        
        <aside class="content"> <!-- right -->
            ...
        </aside>  
    </article>
</section>
```

Comment: what about using figure for the thumbnail?

Comment: Let me ask you: Why did you place the `header`-tag outside the `section`?

Comment: Why would main article content go in an <aside> tag? That makes no sense.